# Trying to open a GUI from a remote server using Mac but not successfully

Tags: linux, ssh, xorg, x11, osx

I'm brand new user in MacOSX.  I'm using ssh to connect to some Linux servers. I'm trying to open a GUI locally for a process running in the remote Linux server.

So I read that I should install XQuartz which is used for the X11 in the Mac.
I installed it but when I try to start the GUI I get error that DISPLAY is not set.

Indeed when I `echo DISPLAY`, nothing has been set. Am I supposed to set something manually?

I also noticed that there is some command line as part of the XQuartz installation. Am I supposed to use only this command line? When I start it and `echo DISPLAY` I see just :0.0. How can I configure this?

I tried `ssh -X` to connect and additionally I also checked out the [X-11 FAQ](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki/X11-UsersFAQ)
According to this something overrides my `DISPLAY` on the local machine. I suspect that TextMate which I installed previously does this, but I'm not sure how can I override it. What should I set? What is: `/tmp/launch-Bh0fLm/:0`?

Comment: :0.0 normally refers to the host graphics adapter. I `ssh` and `ssh -X` into my server at work (to ubuntu from ubuntu) and in both cases `echo $DISPLAY` returned `localhost:10.0`. I do frequently launch gnome apps from remote machine via ssh command line. IMHO, investigate as much as you can about remove X sessions in Mac OSX. Sorry, I don't know more.

Comment: Have you tried using the `-Y` parameter for ssh. Thus, `ssh -Y user@server`. Once connected, you should be able to launch your GUI app from the remote shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following on your Mac OSX system:

Enable X11 Forwarding with the “X11Forwarding yes” option set in `/private/etc/sshd_config` for your SSH daemon's own local X11 host. This will allow the Mac OSX host to receive X11 client requests back from the remote machines (Linux) through ‘ssh‘ with the `-X` option set.

Then restart sshd on the Mac OSX host:

Under System Preference / Sharing pane on Mac OS X. The SSH daemon should be running on the remote machine as well!

Comment: `The SSH daemon should be running on the remote machine as well!` What do you mean?If I am connected via `ssh` to the remote machine then it should be already running, right?

Comment: @Jim - yes that comment means what you said. It was only meant as a reminder, but given you're connecting to the Linux boxes it's moot.